# How to split a string by <span> tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a data.text string that returns a value like:

```
<span>Name</span>Message
```

Is it possible in Javascript to take this value and split in to two so that I can get 'Name' and 'Message' in two different variables?

I tried,

```
var str = data.text;

var arr[] = str.split("</span>", 2);

var str1 = arr[0];
var theRest = arr[1];
```

But didn't work

Comment: Did you try to `split` the string by tag?

Comment: I tried,
    var str=data.text;
    var arr[] = str.split("</span>", 2);
    var str1 = arr[0]; 
    var theRest = arr[1]; 
  But didn't work

Comment: Try this `var str = '<span>Name</span>Message';

var result = str.split(/<\/?span>/);
result.shift();
console.log(result);`

Comment: @Tushar. just answer

Comment: @user2843214 If my answer has helped you solve your problem, kindly mark/accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

There might be many methods but adding on using `split`.

```js
var str = '<span>Name</span>Message';

var result = str.split(/<\/?span>/); // Split by span tags(opening and closing)
result.shift(); // Remove first empty element
console.log(result);
document.write(result);
```

The regex here `<\/?span>` will match the `<span>` and `</span>` both as in the regex `\/?` has made `/` optional.

---

You can also use following regex with non-capturing group.

[**(?:</?span>)(\w+)**](https://regex101.com/r/hF1fV1/1)

```js
var str = '<span>Name</span>Message';

var regex = /(?:<\/?span>)(\w+)/g,
  result = [];

while (res = regex.exec(str)) {
  result.push(res[1]);
}

console.log(result);
document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

[You should use a DOM parser to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

```js
var str = "<span>Name</span>Message",
    el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = str;
[].map.call(el.childNodes, function(node) {
  return node.textContent;
}); // [ "Name", "Message" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the open label with a empty string and then split the string by the close label, something like this:

```
var values = data.text.replace('<span>', '').split('</span>');

console.log(values[0]); // Name
console.log(values[1]); // Message
```