# Javascript split HTML string by span tags

Tags: javascript, matching

I want to split this string into an array using Javascript:

```js
var str = "Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet, <span style='color:red'>consectetur</span> adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>At varius vel<br>pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor."
```

So it will output:

```js
["Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet", "<span style='color:red'>consectetur</span>", "adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>At varius vel<br>pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor."]
```

I'd like this to work with multiple span tags also

Comment: How will the split function behave when it comes to nested span tags?

Comment: Do you need something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800742/how-to-split-a-string-by-span-tag-in-javascript

Comment: @MuzafferGalata I had a look through those solutions, I think they apply to span tags without styles?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a method that avoids making assumptions as to the exact format of the HTML. So rather than using regex to parse it, use DOM parsing directly.

As linked in the comments above, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32801269/14722562) method does it correctly.

However, that solution extracts the `textContent` from all the DOM elements, which is not what you want. You can modify it to instead return the HTML, and in cases where there is none (bare content), return the `textContent`, i.e.

```
return node.outerHTML || node.textContent;
```

But this isn't enough since this approach splits up the entire input HTML into individual nodes, whereas you want splitting to occur only at the `span` tags.

All you need to do to fix this is to "squash" (recombine) the non-`span` elements -- very easily done using `Array.prototype.reduce()`.

Here is a working example of all this in action:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="res">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const str = "Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet, <span style='color:red'>consectetur</span> adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>At varius vel<br>pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor.";

    /* This part is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/32801269/14722562, modified to suit this use case */
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML = str;
    const parsed = [].map.call(el.childNodes, (node) => {
      return node.outerHTML || node.textContent;
    });

    /* This part recombines non-span elements using Array.prototype.reduce() */
    const result = parsed.reduce((r, e) => {
      const el = document.createElement('div');
      el.innerHTML = e;
      if (!el.getElementsByTagName('span').length) {
        r[r.length - 1] += e;
      } else {
        r = r.concat(e, '');
      }
      return r;
    }, ['']).filter(e => e !== '');

    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById('res').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

One caveat here is nested `span` elements. This method will treat nested `span` elements as a single split (though I'm not sure how else you would want it handled). So for example, if your input was:

```
const str = "<span>1.0<span>2.0</span>1.1</span>A<br>B<span>C</span>";
```

then your output would be:

```
["<span>1.0<span>2.0</span>1.1</span>", "A<br>B", "<span>C</span>"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that parses `outerHTML`:

```js
var string = "Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet, <span style='color:red'>consectetur</span> adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>At varius vel<br>pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor." 

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = string;

div.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(span => {
  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(span.outerHTML, '⠀'+span.outerHTML+'⠀'); // Invisible character U+2800
})

string = div.innerHTML.split('⠀'); // U+2800

console.log(string);
```

Comment: Note: this would break in any case that `~` happens to occur in the original HTML string.

Comment: You're right.. Updated the answer to use the invisible character [U+2800](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2800) ^